# Why am I not seeing any Access-Control Headers

Tags: playframework-2.6

I wrote a code to send authentication cookie from `Play` to my Angular application. I notice that I don't see any Acces-Control headers in any of the responses but authentication still works. Does `Play` not send these headers? I was hoping to find some or all of the following headers.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Max-Age
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set them explicitly in the controller action. For example:

```
Ok(content)
  .withHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" -> baseUrl)
```

*See [manipulating http headers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaResults#Manipulating-HTTP-headers) in the play docs.*

Comment: Thanks. I think my question isn't clear. I was expecting to see preflight message but I don't I suppose, one reason could be that I am testing using localhost and not some different origin. Thus I don't see preflight messages with such headers.

Comment: @ManuChadha I see preflight messages, you can see the configuration here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/CorsFilter#Configuring-the-CORS-filter